# Unable to access/consume .cfc service from script

Tags: web-services, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-404, cfc

I am trying to access a web service using `$.ajax` and it shows the below error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://IPAddress/Services.cfc. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

When I try to use the same web service in any of the soap client it works fine.

Comment: Cross domain issue. Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check-angularjs

Comment: I marked your inline code with backticks (`\``) so it's formatted as code and your error as a blockquote using `>`. Please review [Stack Overflow's formatting documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so you can format your posts.