# CORS headers set but still get an error

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, meteor, cors

Hi guys I'm trying to send an ajax request to my meteor app and handle it some way. Here is my code.

```
import { WebApp } from 'meteor/webapp'
import ConnectRoute from 'connect-route'
import { Popups } from '../../imports/collections/popups/Popups'

const Fiber = Npm.require('fibers')

function onRoute (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
  let rawPostBody = ''
  let postData = {}
  req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('on data')
    rawPostBody += chunk.toString()
  })
  req.on('end', function () {
    console.log('on end')
    postData = getPostData(rawPostBody)
    console.log('postData', postData)
    console.log('postData.event', postData.event)
    console.log('postData._id', postData._id)
    Fiber(() => {
      Meteor.call('updateAnalytics', postData, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log('updateAnalytics error', error)
        }
        if (result) {

        }
      })
      console.log('res', res)
      res.writeHead(200)
      res.end()
    }).run()
  })
}

function getPostData (rawPostBody) {
  let postData = {}
  let pairs = rawPostBody.split('&')
  for (let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    let kv = pairs[i].split('=')
    postData[kv[0]] = decodeURIComponent((kv[1] + '').replace(/\+/g, '%20'))
  }
  return postData
}

const middleware = ConnectRoute(function (router) {
  // 2uik9 is for webhooks requests
  router.post('/handlePopups', onRoute)
})

WebApp.connectHandlers.use(middleware)
```

Now when I do an ajax request from chrome console I get this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://b2c.meteorapp.com/handlePopups. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Also nothing is logged in my server console.
But didn't I set the headers? Am I doing it wrong?
Also note when I use a test http request service like [Hurl.it](http://Hurl.it) it gets a response where it shows there are the headers

```
HEADERS

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 14 Mar 2017 10:39:59 GMT
Set-Cookie: galaxy-sticky=ESEFdEqGgiFCeS9P9-ras9; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

And my server console logs everything as it should.

So if my headers are all set what's the problem here?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to mutdmour and Alianp the error is gone, however there is yet another error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://b2c-hayk94.c9users.io/handlePopups. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)` Do you know what's this error is about?

**UPDATE**

Apparently it was a c9 issue. After deploying to galaxy both answers work like a charm, however I accept Alianp's one, because that way I just set the headers for a specific route only.

Comment: Are you testing the pre-flight OPTIONS request with hurl.it? Or just the subsequent GET or POST request?

Comment: @Quentin I think Hurl.it isn't sending an ajax request, so there is no preflight. But why the preflight request doesn't get the headers I set in its response?

Comment: I have been having similar issues recently, does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check-angularjs I found user a browser extension allowed my code to work, a more permanent solution for me would be to configure the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable OPTIONS method for CORS checking.

```
router.options('/handlePopups', function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin,X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
   res.writeHead(200);
   res.end();
});
```

Add this code inside ConnectRoute function and check it.

Comment: Thank you very much.
This results in
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://b2c-hayk94.c9users.io/handlePopups. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)`

Do you know what's this error is about?

Comment: Well apparently this was some issue with c9. After uploading to the galaxy this works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
//server/main.js
WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  return next();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
This results in
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://b2c-hayk94.c9users.io/handlePopups. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)`

Do you know what's this error is about?

Comment: sorry I don't know