# 403 from Elasticsearch call from React Axios

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, axios

I have an Elasticsearch Node running and I can successfully recieve a Json response from the url: `localhost:8882/rest/search/all` using chrome.

However when I call it from react like this:

```
var config = {
          headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    }
        };
axios.get('http://localhost:8882/rest/search/all',config).then(function (response) {...
```

I get a 403 error:
`Failed to load localhost:8882/rest/search/all; Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Comment: Please include any relevant text, in this case the error, in the question not as a screenshot.

Comment: thanks for the remark, i changed the image by text

Comment: This error originates from Chrome actually, not from react or Elastic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check

Comment: Thanks a lot Will Barnwell, it works when i disable web security in chrome with this : Open the start menu
Type windows+R or open "Run"
Execute the following command:
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security