# Why does the browser send an OPTIONS request even though my frontend code is just making a POST request?

Tags: node.js, express, cors, preflight, http-options-method

My front-end code:

```
<form action="" onSubmit={this.search}>
  <input type="search" ref={(input) => { this.searchInput = input; }}/>
  <button type="submit">搜索</button>
</form>

// search method:
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/'; // where the Express server runs
search(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let keyword = this.searchInput.value;
  if (keyword !== this.state.lastKeyword) {
    this.setState({
      lastKeyword: keyword
    });
    fetch(`${baseUrl}search`, {
      method: 'POST',
      // mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }),
      // credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify({keyword})
    })
  }
}
```

And My Express.js server code:

```
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
  next();
});
```

When I submit the form, I get two requests. One of them is an OPTIONS request, and another one is an POST request and the response to it is right:

[image: two requests to /search with response codes 200]
[image: OPTIONS request to localhost:8000/search]
[image: POST request to localhost:8000/search]

As you can see, the Express server runs on port 8000, and the React development server runs on port 3000. `localhost:3000` is requesting `localhost:8000/search`, and `localhost:8000` is requesting another origin via using a POST method. However, only the second request works well. I don't know how this happen. Of course, If I make a GET request with querystring, things are normal. But I also want to know how to make a POST fetch with the request body.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That `OPTIONS` request is sent automatically by your browser on its own, before it tries the `POST` request from your code. It’s called a CORS preflight.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests has details.

The gist of it in this specific case is that the `Content-Type: application/json` request header that the code is adding is what triggers the browser to do that preflight `OPTIONS` request.

So the purpose of that particular preflight request is for the browser to ask the server, *“Do you allow cross-origin `POST` requests that have a `Content-Type` header whose value isn’t one of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`?”*

And for the browser to consider the preflight successful, the server must send back a response with an [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Headers)  header that includes `Content-Type` in its value.

So I see that you’ve got `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')` in your current server code on `http://localhost:8000/`, and that’s the right value to set if you’re going to code it manually that way. But I think the reason that’s not working is because you don’t also have code that explicitly handles `OPTIONS` requests.

To fix that, you might try instead installing the npm `cors` package:

```
npm install cors
```

…and then doing something like this:

```js
var express = require('express')
  , cors = require('cors')
  , app = express();
const corsOptions = {
  origin: true,
  credentials: true
}
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions)); // preflight OPTIONS; put before other routes
app.listen(80, function(){
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80');
});
```

That’ll handle the `OPTIONS` request, while also sending back the right headers and values.

Comment: Thanks! I know that my `fetch()` function and the code that set response headers are not good, and I've tried many times(maybe you can see that many code is being commented). Can you tell me how to use `fetch` and set response headers correctly?

Comment: Your `fetch` call is fine. But you need to enable CORS support in the `http://localhost:8000/` server that the request is being sent to. See up my updated answer. That’ll cause the server to handle the preflight OPTIONS request correctly, and to send the necessary CORS headers back. Without that, your browser will block your frontend JavaScript code from being able to send that `POST` request as long as you’re adding that `Content-Type: application/json` request header to the request.

Comment: In my case the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Method` were not enough, I had to add `Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400` to make it work. I guess the browser needs the information for how long the "access rights" are valid

Answer (score -2):

I faced similar problem recently and use FormData to send my request payload, and you don't need to send custom headers. FormData object takes care of the authentication credential for you, but it uses SSL and can only work with https which is not provided by localhost because local host uses http protocol.
Check form-data [npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) for detail information on how to install and use it in your express app but FormData is readily available for use in major browsers.
here a simple code example
npm install --save form-data

`

```
var FormData = require('form-data');
var http = require('http'); 
var form = new FormData();
 
http.request('http://nodejs.org/images/logo.png', function(response) {
  form.append('my_field', 'my value');
  form.append('my_buffer', new Buffer(10));
  form.append('my_logo', response);
});
```

`

Comment: "you don't need to send custom headers" — Yes, you do.

Comment: "FormData object takes care of the authentication credential for you" — No, it doesn't.

Comment: "can only work with https which is not provided by localhost because local host uses http protocol" — Nothing is stopping you from installing a server that supports HTTPS and listens on localhost … and FormData works just fine with HTTP anyway.

Comment: "Check form-data npm documentation for detail information on how to install and use it in your express app" — They are making the request **from the browser** so that doesn't help.