# CORS related problem, i cannot proceed to a POST request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, promise

I'm having some troubles trying to make my backend and front communicate to each others (reactjs + vanilla NODEjs), both on different localhost port (4000 and 3000)

I managed to make it work until i wanted to try to add data to my database.
I can GET data with my react app but i can't POST any data.
Here is the code for both sides :

front :
`

```
const sendData = async (event: any): Promise<void> => {
    console.log("hello");
    event.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch(`${_DATA_URL_}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(employeeForm),
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  };
```

`
back :

```
const Router = (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
  );
  console.log("hello"); //debug
  if (req.method === "GET") {
    if (req.url === "/api/employees") {
      getEmployees(req, res);
    } else if (req.url.match(/\/api\/employees\/(\w{4}-?){3}/)) {
      const requestID = req.url.split("/")[3];

      getEmployee(req, res, requestID);
    } else {
      res.statusCode = 404;

      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      res.end(JSON.stringify({ message: `Error : ${req.url} not found !` }));
    }
  }
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    if (req.url === "/api/employees") {
      createEmployee(req, res);
    } else {
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      res.end(JSON.stringify({ message: `Error : ${req.url} not found !` }));
    }
  }
  if (req.method === "DELETE") {
    if (req.url.match(/\/api\/employees\/(\w{4}-?){3}/)) {
      const requestID = req.url.split("/")[3];
      deleteEmployee(req, res, requestID);
    } else {
      res.statusCode = 404;

      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      res.end(JSON.stringify({ message: `Error : ${req.url} not found !` }));
    }
  }
  if (req.method === "PUT") {
    if (req.url.match(/\/api\/employees\/(\w{4}-?){3}/)) {
      const requestID = req.url.split("/")[3];
      updateEmployee(req, res, requestID);
    } else {
      res.statusCode = 404;

      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      res.end(JSON.stringify({ message: `Error : ${req.url} not found !` }));
    }
  }
};
```

i'm pretty sure it comes from react side because posting data works fine when i use POSTMAN, and after a while on localhost i receive this error in the console :

[image]

Maybe i'm using cors incorrectly, anyways thanks for your futures answers

Comment: Please dont post images but add the error code as snippet here.  Apart from this, the error does not look like its CORS related. Its saying `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`, perhaps you have some other bug in your backend.

Comment: in your post handler, when you create the employee, maybe you forgot to call `res.end`. Its hard to tell because you dont show that function but you pass in the response object, so it seems like this is at least your intention.

Comment: Hello, yes its a bit confusing beacuse it seems there is no place (at least in the code) where this could happen, here is the link of my repo where i store it [link](https://github.com/nathanLR/myemployeesmanagerbackend/tree/main/logic)

Comment: It could happen if you have an error in the try block in that createEmplyee function. I see that in this case `res.end` is not called which would lead to the error you show. `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` looks really like your server is never responding properly.

Comment: Ah, yes as you show, you also don't handle the options request, and thus don't respond properly in that case either. Btw, I dont think your current answer qualifies as one in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,

answer [here](https://boutdecode.fr/article/cors-avec-nodejs) (in french) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904400/why-does-the-browser-send-an-options-request-even-though-my-frontend-code-is-jus)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).