# Observable does not returns api response

Tags: php, angular, api

I am  new in angular.
My Project is in angular5 and I am using a web API created in PHP.
My WebApi gives response in postman but not from angular.
I am using HttpClient to post request

```
    export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {
      private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/fullpath';
      private response;
      private data=[];

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.response =this.getCategory();
      }

      getCategory (): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(this.apiUrl,{});
      }

      ngOnInit() {
       console.log(this.response);
      }
  }
```

My console Returns
[image]

What I have to do to get proper response from API?

Comment: You're not subscribing to the observable anywhere.

Comment: Try this: `return this.http.post(this.apiUrl,{}).subscribe()` in `getCategory` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Observables, you have to subscribe to them. 
 The actual user of the observable needs to subscribe(), because without 
 subscribe() the observable won't be executed at all.

subscribe() returns a Subscription that can not be subscribed to, but it can be used to cancel the subscription.

```
 getCategory (): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.post(this.apiUrl,{}).subscribe(
         //Do whatever
        (res)=> console.log(res), 
        (error)=> console.log(error)
      );
    }
```

For more information you can go to the Angular documentation for Observables:
https://angular.io/guide/observables.

Also, remember that most of the subscriptions terminate by themselves, but is always good practice to terminate them using `ngOnDestroy();` to avoid memory leaks.

**How to use ngDestroy()?**
In you component.ts file
Make sure you have the import

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
export class YourComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 .
 .
 .
 ngOnDestroy() {
   this.response.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Now, related to your CORS Problem, reference the question that has been asked on stackoverflow before:
[Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check)

Comment: Great! How to use ngOnDestroy() ? Just set in component? Thanks!

Comment: @Chiien updated my answer showing how to use ngOnDestroy

Comment: @Raman remember that for some http request (depending on the server) the server has to be hosting a .json file. e.g `https://mypage.com/data.json`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.getCategory().subscribe(response => {
       console.log(response);
    }, err => {
       console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to an Observable to consume it.

Instead of this

```
private http: HttpClient) {
    this.response =this.getCategory();
}
```

Try this

```
private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getCategory().subscribe(result => this.responce = result);
}
```

Comment: Failed to load http://localhost:8080/fullpath: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Any Help please

Comment: For that, you need to set CORS domain in server PHP!

Answer (score 0):

Great! You can try that

```
this.getCategory().subscribe(
    response => console.log(response),
    err => console.log(err)
);
```

But the best way to use that, you need to create service for POST Request, and you just call him im component. Like that

```
getCategory(data: any): Observable<any> {
 return this._http.post(`url`, JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

And use that in component

```
this.categoryService.getCategory(data).subscribe(
 data => console.log(data),
 err => console.log(err)
)
```

And you can use Google DevTools to see if is worked the request, and see the request Response! In `network`! If problem is CORS, you need to set CORS domain in your server!
Try that and tell me if worked! Hope that helps! Thanks