# OPENTOK REST API doesn't work

Tags: cors, opentok, tokbox

[EDIT] The description of my post was bad, sorry for my English, I start again.
What I mean is when I make a request ajax rest to api opentok from localhost, I have this error:

Failed to load https://api.opentok.com/v2/project//broadcast: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access.

And this code represents the ajax query:

```
var dataLiveStreamRequestBody = {
                      "sessionId": sessionId,
                      "layout": {
                        "type": "bestfit",
                      },
                      "maxDuration": 5400,
                      "outputs": {
                        "hls": {},
                        "rtmp": [{
                          "id": "<adresse_ip>",
                          "serverUrl": "rtmp://<adresse_ip>/<streamname>/toto",
                          "streamName": "<stream-name>"
                        }]
                      },
                      "resolution": "640x480"
                    };



                $.ajax({
                  contentType: 'application/json',
                  data: JSON.stringify(dataLiveStreamRequestBody),
                  dataType: 'json',
                  beforeSend: function(xhr){
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-OPENTOK-AUTH', '<token>');
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
                  },
                  success: function(data){
                      console.log("live streaming broadcast succeeded");
                  },
                  error: function(){
                      console.log("live streaming broadcast failed");
                  },
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'https://api.opentok.com/v2/project/'+ apiKey +'/broadcast'
                });
```

I followed the instructions on this page: https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/#start_broadcast

Answer (score 0):

Tokbox QA staff here.

Not sure what you're trying to do, but maybe this can help:

https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/#start_broadcast

On the other hand, that IP 127.0.0.1:8081 does not look very well, because it's an internal address. Where does that IP come from?

Comment: This ip is my localhost adress, I make a request to opentok api from localhost application. This is the origin.

Comment: You can't use that IP, 127.0.0.1, because then, OpenTok server cannot access YOUR server. You must use its public address

Answer (score 0):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

You should be making the `startBroadcast` call from your server because the call requires the `X-OPENTOK-AUTH` header which is generated using your `apiKey` and `apiSecret`. The `apiSecret` should not be exposed on the client side because it's used to generate OpenTok [sessions](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/basics/#sessions) and [tokens](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/basics/#token).

Also, here's a StackOverflow answer that explains what to do when you run into that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`issue : [Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check)

Comment: Thanks, indeed the problem was related at "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", your issue had the solution.