# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N67n7.png)Hi everyone my application's Backend in ASP.Net Core 2.0 and Frontend in React Web,
I just implemented SignalR But due to issue am not able to create the connection between Client and Server

Error: OPTIONS http://XXXX.XXXX.XXX/chathub/negotiate 405 (Method Not Allowed)
XXXX.XXX.XXX/:1 Failed to load http://XXX.XXX.XXX.227/XXXX/chathub/negotiate: Response to the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em4z7.png)preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX:8017' is therefore not allowed access.

**Startup File:**

```
services.AddSignalR();

services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(DefaultCorsPolicyName, builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
            });
```

**Even I also tried with Origin**

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
          options.AddPolicy(DefaultCorsPolicyName, builder => 
          builder.WithOrigins("http://XXX.XXX.XXX")
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
            });


app.UseSignalR(route =>
{
     route.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
});

app.UseCors(DefaultCorsPolicyName); //Enable CORS!
```

Please help me am stuck with this issue

Thanks,

Comment: You have to handle Cors **BEFORE** you handle SignalR. Just put the `UseCors`  registration before `UseSignalR`.The middlewares are executed in the order they are registered with `UseXxx`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check)