# How to allow cross origin in Angular 7?

Tags: angular7

I have received the error message while working with Angular 7

**localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:58523/api/DashboardLoaderService/1' from origin 'http://localhost:59484' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35588856