# How to make an authenticated PUT request to an App Engine service from an other origin

Tags: http, google-app-engine, authentication, google-authentication

I have an App Engine service with a few methods implemented, where I restrict all routes with the [login: admin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_login) option in the app.yaml.

Making a POST request to my service works:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8081/api/foo', {
  credentials: 'include'});
```

But making a PUT request fails

```
await fetch('http://localhost:8081/api/foo', {
  credentials: 'include',
  method: 'PUT',
  body: 'hi there'});
```

with the following error:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

I understand this is because my request is somehow not authenticated, and the server redirects my request to the login page. What I don't understand is how to authenticate it.

I'm using webapp2 to process the requests, and setting the following headers:

```py
self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
# This feels wrong, but I still don't clearly understand what this header's purpose is...
self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = self.request.headers['Origin']
```

I think the deeper problem is that I don't undestand how this login feature works (is it cookie based? Why does it work with GET but not PUT? ...), and I don't truly understand CORS either.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `login: admin` configuration is  based on the [Users API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/users/), available only in the 1st generation standard environment. Not a CORS problem. From the `login` row in the [handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) table:

> When a URL handler with a **login** setting other than **optional**
>   matches a URL, the handler first checks whether the user has signed in
>   to the application using its [authentication option](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/users/#Python_Authentication_options). If not, by
>   default, the user is redirected to the sign-in page. You can also use
>   [`auth_fail_action`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_auth_fail_action) to configure the app to simply reject requests
>   for a handler from users who are not properly authenticated, instead
>   of redirecting the user to the sign-in page.

To use the Users API the user must literally login before the `PUT` request is made. Make a `GET` request first, which will redirect you to the login page, execute the login, then make the `PUT` request.

If that's not something you can achieve then you need to use [a different authentication mechanism](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/oauth/#users_api), not the one based on `login: admin`.

**Update**:

The above is true, but rather unrelated as the Users API authentication is addressed - you did mention that some other request method to the same URL works.

The error you get is indeed CORS-related, see [Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check). But I'd suggest not focusing on the accepted answer (which is only about working around CORS), but rather on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36446460/4495081), which is about doing CORS correctly.

Comment: Thanks... but I still don't quite understand: I'm making the request while the client is already logged in, and It works with a GET request. I guess this is related to the GET request not needing a preflight request, but I don't know how I can authenticate the preflight with the users API (currently, it's getting redirected to the login page)

Comment: I see, my answer is off - you do get a CORS-related error ;) I'll update.

Comment: I have managed to go around the problem by disabling the login:admin option and instead using users.is_current_user_admin() in my handlers, except for the 'options' handler, where I only set some headers. I don't like manually checking credentials: it feels very error-prone. I'd much rather find a solution to make that preflight request work with the "auth: admin" option.

Comment: That's rather easy: just create a base class for all your handlers, implementing the actual `<method>()` functions (i.e. `get()` & friends) which would enforce the check before calling `self.handle_<method>()`. In the child classes you'd implement just the `handle_<method>()` functions instead of the `<method>()` ones.

Comment: That makes sense... Thanks! I'll put all of that together, make sure everything works, and accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, after discussing with Dan Cornilescu, here is the solution I came up with (Thanks Dan!)

Instead of having my classes inherit webapp2.RequestHandler, they inherit this custom HandlerWrapper.
The big difference is that when receiving an 'OPTIONS' request (ie. preflight), there is no login required. This is what was causing my problem: I couldn't get the preflight request to be authenticated, so now it doesn't need to be.

The CORS is also handled there, with a list of allowed origins

```py
class HandlerWrapper(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def __init__(self, request, response):
    super(HandlerWrapper, self).__init__(request, response)

    self.allowed_origins = [
      r'http://localhost(:\d{2,})?$', # localhost on any port
      r'https://\w+-dot-myproject.appspot.com' # all services in the app engine project
    ]
    self.allowed_methods = 'GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS'
    self.content_type = 'application/json'
    # login mode: either 'admin', 'user', or 'public'
    self.login = 'admin'

  def dispatch(self):
    # set the Allow-Origin header.
    if self.request.headers.has_key('origin') and match_origin(self.request.headers['Origin'], self.allowed_origins):
      self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = self.request.headers['Origin']

    # set other headers
    self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = self.allowed_methods
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'

    # Handle preflight requests: Never require a login.
    if self.request.method == "OPTIONS":
      # For some reason, the following line raises a '405 (Method Not Allowed)'
      # error, so we just skip the dispatch and it works.
      # super(HandlerWrapper, self).dispatch()
      return

    # Handle regular requests
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if self.login == 'admin' and not users.is_current_user_admin():
      self.abort(403)
    elif self.login == 'user' and not user:
      self.abort(403)
    else:
      super(HandlerWrapper, self).dispatch()

def match_origin(origin, allowed_origins):
  for pattern in allowed_origins:
    if re.match(pattern, origin): return True
  return False
```