# CORS issue from AngularJS frontend to Spring rest backend

Tags: angularjs, cors, spring-rest

I have front-end AngularJS application & spring rest back-end application both deployed in the same tomcat with same port, their contexts are different. I can access spring rest endpoints from Postman. But my front-end cannot access the back-end, because of CORS policy. The error message is

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://sbr-devp-55:8080/BackendWS/administration/getLabels' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have tried following approach: writing a CORSFilter as follows:

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers,"
                        + " Authorization, X-Requested-With,startTime ");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);

}

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    //initialization code
}

public void destroy() {
    //destroy code
}
```

I have written an initializer like this:

```
public class BackendWSInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { BackendWSConfiguration.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {

    Filter [] singleton = { new CORSFilter(),new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter()};
    return singleton;
}
```

}

What more I need to do? And why the origin is http://localhost:8080? Not http://sbr-devp-55:8080? Do I have to do something at the AngularJS side? And strangely this works without any CORS issue in 2 other developer's machine.Could it be any certificate issue? Error message does not indicate any such thing.

This is how it shows up in F12 > console:

```
    POST http://sbr-devp-55:8080/BackendWS/administration/getLabels 404 (Not Found)
localization.js:108 {data: "", status: 404, headers: ƒ, config: {…}, statusText: "Not Found"}
config: data: {clientId: 92, projectId: 334, languageId: 1, userId: -1}
headers: {Content-Type: "application/json;", Accept: "application/json;", startTime: 1557157292135}method: "POST"
paramSerializer: ƒ ngParamSerializer(params)timeout: 600000
transformRequest: [ƒ]transformResponse: [ƒ]
url: "http://SBR-DEVP-55:8080/BackendWS/administration/getLabels"
__proto__: Objectdata: ""headers: ƒ (name)status: 404statusText: "Not Found"__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar issue reported for XMLHTTP request 
[Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Are you using Angular < 2 ?

For other 2 developers, check what is the request header getting passed and compare with yours ? Is their any proxy defined in your machine ?

Comment: no proxy in my machine. I am using AngularJS i.e. Angular 1.x.x. My machine is Windows 10.

Comment: try with way to run from Command CLI  . chromium-browser --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="[some directory here]"  this to disable CORS rules validation from browser perspective. So you can isolate is it specific to xmlhttprequest (or) java server side. If it works, then it seems to be a issue in Java Filter handling Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check Ref 2 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Comment: I have added the chrome plugin :Allow-Control-Allow-Origin:*, will report back if it works.Also modified the CORSFilter to include "Origin" header.

Comment: In the CORSFilter already present, I added "Origin" header - because of that or for whatever reason the problem got solved.It is like following:                                     response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,Content-Type,accept Access-Control-Allow-Headers,       Authorization, X-Requested-With,startTime ");