# Simple authorization in react axios error: `Network Error at createError...`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I want to test my app and get data from api. When I'm logged in to the web I check in the `network` tab, which returns me `request url` in `headers`, example: `https: // beta.application.com / api / v1 / projects /`. Is it possible for me to refer to this url in my app?

In console.log I have error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401
>   (Unauthorized)
>
> Access to https: // beta.application.com / api / v1 / projects / at from origin 'chrome-extension://ccekbkp' has
>   been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
>   pass access control check: The value of the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
>   wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The
>   credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
>
> Network Error
>       at createError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:87)

Example:

> email: john.asd@gmail.com
>
> password: aZdfgHkL12

In `local.storage` I have access to token
Example: `{access_token:" 111111111111111111 "}

Can I copy this token and use it in my app in React?

I'm trying to do it:

```
  componentDidMount() {
        const token = '111111111111111111'; //token from local.storage 
       /*const hash = Base64.encode(token);
        const Basic = 'Basic ' + hash;*/
        const username= 'john.asd@gmail.com';
        const password= 'aZdfgHkL12'
        const url= "https://beta.application.com/api/v1/projects/";

        axios.get
            axios({
                "url": url,
                "withCredentials": true,
                "method": "GET",
                "headers": {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                },
                "auth": {
                    username: username,
                    password: password
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    projects: response
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('error');
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const token = '111111111111111111'; //token from local.storage 
    const url= "https://beta.application.com/api/v1/projects";

    axios.get
        axios({
            "url": url,
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                projects: response
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('error');
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Regarding `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status` you might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35588856/4512646), seems like a CORS issue. 
If this is an extension you should add the proper [permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) and content_security_policy to your manifest (also might need to white-list your extension server side).

Regarding the token, you should send it to your server in the header, depending on what the server expects:

```
headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
          }
```

You can even create a new axios instance to avoid adding it all the time:

```
axiosInstance = axios.create({
     headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
     }
});
```

and then use it to make your requests to the sever

Comment: I add  `"permissions": [
    "https://*/",  "http://*/"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"`; but I have still the same errors

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: `has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`

Comment: Should look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19744754/4512646
"If you want to allow credentials then your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` must not use `*`." on your server

Comment: I had to delete `withCredentials` and `auth`