# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: reactjs, laravel, rest

Using React as frontend and laravel as backend.

I get the following error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sub.example.com/api/test' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

This is my Kernel.php

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];
```

And this is my config/cors.php

```
<?php

return [
    'paths' => ['api/*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['GET', 'POST'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => false,
    'max_age' => false,
    'supports_credentials' => false,
];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check)

Comment: What browser are you using? If its Chrome, it has CORS handling built in, you will get a different result with Postman or another browser. Try installing and using `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc`

Comment: @Harmenx in Safari I just get: Preflight response is not successful