# Angular blocked by CORS policy preflight response

Tags: angular, cors, token, angular12

I'm making a reques in Angular 12, with a valid token in the header, in postman it works, however, if I run it from the browser, I get the following error, `from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

This is part of the core, it's in a service.

```
token: string = 'eyJ4NXQiOiJNek15Wm1aaE9ERm...';
   headers= new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-type', 'application/json')
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS')
    .set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ this.token);
  getUniversal4(): Observable<Catalog>{
    console.log(this.headers);
    return this.http.get<Catalog>(this.urlEndpointBS, {headers: this.headers});
    //return this.http.get(this.urlEndpoint).pipe( map( response => response));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty self explanatory: your API server needs to respond to the preflight request (OPTIONS) with a header called `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` that contains the `Authorization` header.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the code works in Postman is that Postman does not send preflight requests whereas, your browser does.

You either can add this to your backend server:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*'
```

Or you can use proxy [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d). Just bear in mind that the proxy can be used only in the development - ng serve - and does not work in the production.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is a long read I strongly suggest to go through the [CORS page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), in short:

When you trigger a request from JavaScript to an *origin* other of the one of the page itself, the server needs to respond with the appropriate HTTP headers - i.e. `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` - to the *preflight request* made by the browser so the browser security does not block the request.

For a longer answer [see this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66251198/11932806) of a duplicate question.