# How to fix CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cors

I'm trying to send a `POST` request to my `Express` server, but it always throws this error

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4000/users/sign-up' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

And this is how I setup my server "using TypeScript"

```
import express, { Application } from 'express';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { databaseConnect, serverConnect } from './modules/connections';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import devicesRouter from './routes/dashboard';
import usersRouter from './routes/users';
import announcementsRouter from './routes/announcements';
import ordersRouter from './routes/orders';

// Initializing express
const app: Application = express();

// Server configurations
dotenv.config();
await databaseConnect();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000", credentials: true }));

// Defining server routes
app.use('/devices', devicesRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/announcements', announcementsRouter);
app.use('/orders', ordersRouter);

// Connecting server
serverConnect();
```

And in my client I'm using the `fetch API` to send the post request

```
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/users/sign-up", { method: "POST", headers: { "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000" }, body: JSON.stringify(signUpData) });
```

I have seen many videos about fixing this error just by installing the `cors` package, but somehow it didn't work for me.

I tried to reinstall both the `cors` and `@types/cors` packages but nothing changes.

I also tried using

```
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://192.168.1.3:3000", credentials: true }));
```

instead of

```
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000", credentials: true }));
```

but it did't work as well.

Comment: you're fetching from port 4000, but you set the cors origin to 3000 - was this intended?

Comment: @Alfie The origin is where the request originates from, not the destination.

Comment: Can you try adding this before any route.  app.options('*', cors())

Comment: @Yogi Unfortunately, it doesn't. if you take a look at my request headers you can see the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" property set to "http://localhost:3000"

Comment: CORS and localhost don't play nicely together. [Why does my http://localhost CORS origin not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/why-does-my-http-localhost-cors-origin-not-work)

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, my bad, I suppose really I meant just to double check this (is OP trying to execute the code from port 3000, 4000, or other?)

Comment: @Alfie I tried using an asterisk symbol instead of defining a specific route but It did't work

Comment: @CodeThing Just tried it but unfortunately it did't work

Comment: I think @DanielBeck's comment is the answer. I seem to recall having a similar issue when using Chrome in the past.

Comment: Your error message says, it did not found Access-Control-Allow-Origin on the request header. So there is definitely something wrong with sending request. Can you try deleting that header origin. Is it working from Postman?

Comment: @Alfie I tried @DenielBeck's answer `app.use(cors({ origin: "http://192.168.1.3:3000", credentials: true }));
` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @CodeThing Yes it does, I tried it using Postman and Thunder Clinet VS code extension and it's working fine.

Comment: @SaifEssam Are you confirming it works when testing not using Chrome?

Comment: @SaifEssam - a few things. 1. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is meant to be a **Response** header, not a request one. It makes no difference if you include it in your request. 2. I think it's working with HTTP clients because they don't send an `origin` header at all. 3. try [editing your hosts file](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/modify-the-hosts-file-on-windows-10/) and add a different domain for `127.0.0.1`, for example - `my_app`. Then set the `Allow-Origin` in the node.js code to be `my_app:3000` and access `my_app:4000`. **Be sure to restart Node between changes.**

Comment: or add different domains that point to `127.0.0.1`. makes no difference.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check. Also is there any reason you set credentials option to true?

Comment: Drop this `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from your request.

Comment: @Alfie Yes it works out side chrome.

Comment: @Yarin_007 I have updated the question and I included your answer.

Comment: You'll need to explicitly allow the `Content-Type` header in your CORS configuration.

Comment: I have solved it and posted the answer, it was my fault. Thank you all.

Comment: @Yogi At the app level it’s enabled by default: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, the problem was in the `serverConnect()` function.
I was initializong a new instace of `express` when I call the function and that was the reason why I get the errors.

I was doing it like this

```
export function serverConnect() {
    const app: Application = express(); // <== This line was is what causes the error

    try {
        app.listen(4000, () => console.log("✅  Server is connected successfully"));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("  Error starting the server\n", error);
    }
}
```

I changed it to this and it works fine

```
export function serverConnect(app: Application) {
    try {
        app.listen(4000, () => console.log("✅  Server is connected successfully"));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("  Error starting the server\n", error);
    }
}
```

**Thanks for your contributions. it was my fault from beginning.**

Answer (score -1):

You can use express cors middleware: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: '*', // <-- this, as mentioned in the docs linked above, or change it to whatever your origin is
}
```

Comment: According to the post’s code snippet they’re already using it.

Comment: with option: origin: '*' (or whatever your origin is, e.g. http://localhost:9000)

Comment: According to the post’s code snippet they’re already setting the origin option.

Comment: @dude I tried it before but it didn't work.