# Accessing Google RSS return 403

Tags: reactjs, rss

so I'm building a Reactjs application and using this google rss url `https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=Industri+Mekanik+Elektrik&hl=id&gl=ID&ceid=ID:id`; to show some news feed

but when i fetch it using javascript fetch it return
`Access to fetch at 'https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=Industri+Mekanik+Elektrik&hl=id&gl=ID&ceid=ID:id' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

am I missing something like should I register an api key here or anything else ?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check)

Comment: @egemenakturk i mean even if i can solve it in my local using some proxy or browser extension im afraid it will still error when go live (using real server)