# API works on postman but return Cors error in js file

Tags: javascript, angular, cors, fetch-api

I'm trying to call a POST API with fetch method in js,

When I test it in postman it returns 200OK but when I want to use it in my own project, I receive cors error. I don't have access to backend server so any other tips?
Here's my code in js file :

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', () => {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    myHeaders.append('Accept', 'application/json');

    var raw = JSON.stringify({
        "FromAirport": "IIH",
        "ToAirport": "DIH",
        "FromDate": "2023-04-05",
        "Adult": "1",
        "Child": "0",
        "Infant": "0",
        "MemberSessionID": "4D6CCC-9E80-40EC-B89D-2B8064A",
        "AllinFromCity": false,
        "AllinToCity": false,
        "TestMode": false,
        "classType": "ECONOMY"
    });

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw,
        redirect: 'follow',
       /* mode : 'no-cors'*/
    };

    fetch("https://testapi.exampleflight.com/flight/search/E08558B2263436736D43E67FC85EDD95", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log('response : ', result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error : ', error));
```

Comment: You can not resolve this in frontend, because your Browser blocks the request as a result of your api response. You can try to ad your own backend as a proxy, which makes  the request to the foreign api.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check)

Comment: Enable the CORS from your backend.