# Getting error: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check" only when I pass Authorization header from my react app

Tags: reactjs, cors, header, authorization, preflight

Getting error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

only when I pass `Authorization` header from my react app. When I do not pass `Authorization` header, api call works properly.

We have Java API to fetch the data and using Google App Engine as a datastore.  In java api we have added following line of code to avoid CORS issue:

```java
HttpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

To achieve security to the api call we are trying to implement encryption. For that api is expecting `Authorization: Bearer key` to be passed while calling api.

Through postman when I call this api It is working properly.

But when I try to call Api through my react app using following code it gives me error as:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**React code which is giving above error:**

```
  Axios
            .get(apiurl, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer NTY1OTMxMzU4NjU2OTIxNg==' } })
            .then((response) => response.data)
            .then((json) => {
                console.log(json);               
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Failed to fetch.");
            });
```

When I remove header from api call then it doesn't give above error.

**React code which does not give above error:**

```
  Axios
            .get(apiurl)
            .then((response) => response.data)
            .then((json) => {
                console.log(json);               
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Failed to fetch.");
            });
```

I tried to set the specific domain name in java code but it didn't work. Such as:

```java
HttpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://squid-app-ik7i3.ondigitalocean.app");
```

I tried to set header as follows but it didn't work:

```java
HttpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Authorization");
```

I am expecting data from API when I pass correct `Authorization` token but I am getting error as:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Please let me know If I am missing something in api call or any specific code required to be added in java file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check-no-access-con)

Comment: What is the Web origin of your client? Is it really `https://squid-app-ik7i3.ondigitalocean.app`?

Comment: Yes https://squid-app-ik7i3.ondigitalocean.app is the web origin. I have deployed application on digitaloceon server and got this as web link.